# I want to select the multiple day using getx flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to select the days depending on my requirements like i want to select **SUN, TUE, WED**
These three days will initially be **blue**, but once I click on them, they will be selected and turn **red**, indicating that I have chosen those days. I can choose more. I can also change the selection by deselecting it, and it will return to blue.
I write a code in my controller but its not updating the ui when i click on the day. I used ListView.builder and model for the days.

** This my code page**

```
import 'package:base_project/app/core/theme/text_theme.dart';
import 'package:base_project/app/core/translations/translation_keys.dart';
import 'package:base_project/app/core/value/colors.dart';
import 'package:base_project/app/core/value/dimensions.dart';
import 'package:base_project/app/features/rider_info/rider_pages/office_working_days/office_working_days_controller.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../../../../routes/app_routes.dart';

class MyOfficeWorkingDaysAre extends GetView<OfficeWorkingDaysController> {
  MyOfficeWorkingDaysAre({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: AppPadding.contentLarge,
              right: AppPadding.contentLarge,
              top: AppPadding.contentSmall),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    size: 40,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 70.0,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/calender.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(TranslationKeys.myOfficeWorkingDaysAre.tr,
                        style: AppTextStyle.headline1),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Obx(
                () => Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: controller.daysList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Row(
                          children: [
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                controller.toggle(index);
                              },
                              child: ClipRect(
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundColor:
                                      controller.isSelected.value == index
                                          ? Colors.red
                                          : Colors.blue,
                                  radius: 45,
                                  child: Text(
                                    controller.daysList[index].daysName ?? "",
                                    style: AppTextStyle.headline2
                                        ?.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 5,
                            )
                          ],
                        );
                      }),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Get.toNamed(Routes.dailyschedule);
        },
        backgroundColor: AppColors.floatingButtonColor,
        child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

** This my Controller page**

```
import 'package:base_project/app/features/rider_info/rider_pages/office_working_days/model/days_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class OfficeWorkingDaysController extends GetxController {
  final RxInt isSelected = 0.obs;

   toggle(int index) {
    isSelected.value = index;
    print("The clicked index is $index");
  }

  RxList<DaysModel> daysList = [
    DaysModel(id: 1, daysName: "SUN"),
    DaysModel(id: 2, daysName: "MON"),
    DaysModel(id: 3, daysName: "TUE"),
    DaysModel(id: 4, daysName: "WED"),
    DaysModel(id: 5, daysName: "THU"),
    DaysModel(id: 6, daysName: "FRI"),
    DaysModel(id: 7, daysName: "SAT"),
  ].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
  }

  void test() {
    debugPrint("test: ");
  }
}
```

[image: This my Ui like it is scrollable]

Comment: add selected property to DaysModel instead of one selected variable

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by just using GetBuilder instead of Obx, Here's the code of the view and the controller file:

1. View File

```js
class MyOfficeWorkingDaysAre extends StatelessWidget {
  MyOfficeWorkingDaysAre({super.key});
  final controller = Get.put(OfficeWorkingDaysController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  size: 40,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 70.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                  child: const Icon(Icons.calculate),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Text("Dummy Text"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            GetBuilder(builder: (OfficeWorkingDaysController controller) {
              return Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: controller.daysList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Row(
                        children: [
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              controller.toggle(index);
                              // controller.refresh();
                            },
                            child: ClipRect(
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundColor:
                                    controller.isSelected.value == index
                                        ? Colors.red
                                        : Colors.blue,
                                radius: 45,
                                child: Text(
                                  controller.daysList[index].daysName,
                                  // style: AppTextStyle.headline2
                                  // ?.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 5,
                          )
                        ],
                      );
                    }),
              );
            }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Get.toNamed(Routes.dailyschedule);
        },
        // backgroundColor: AppColors.floatingButtonColor,
        child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

2. Controller File

```js
class OfficeWorkingDaysController extends GetxController {
  Rx<int> isSelected = 0.obs;

  void toggle(int index) {
    isSelected.value = index;
    update();
    print("The clicked index is $index");
    print("The clicked index is ${isSelected.value}");
  }

  RxList<DaysModel> daysList = [
    DaysModel(id: 1, daysName: "SUN"),
    DaysModel(id: 2, daysName: "MON"),
    DaysModel(id: 3, daysName: "TUE"),
    DaysModel(id: 4, daysName: "WED"),
    DaysModel(id: 5, daysName: "THU"),
    DaysModel(id: 6, daysName: "FRI"),
    DaysModel(id: 7, daysName: "SAT"),
  ].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
  }

  void test() {
    debugPrint("test: ");
  }
}
```